# Access an application running in a Docker Container which is running inside an emulated CoreOS in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, docker, cloud9-ide, coreos

My problem is: I am running an application called Cloud9 inside a container, this application runs at default on localhost:3131, but it is changeable. This Docker Container is running on a CoreOS VM, and the CoreOS VM is running on Ubuntu 14.04 through VirtualBox.

What I need is: from the browser on Ubuntu be able to access the Cloud9 application running inside Docker.

I have tried several things to work on the Docker Network (Pipeworks, Docker0 settings, VirtualBox settings, etc), but I am completely stuck,

How could I access the application through all this layers: Ubuntu > CoreOS > Docker > Cloud9 ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll have to post the details of your configuration. How is your VirtualBox networking configured? What ports do your Dockerfile expose? Do it one layer at a time; if you ssh into your VM can you access the service from there?

Comment: I have two adapters for CoreOs in the VirtualBox: the first one is NAT and there is two forward port rules 

**1.** ssh; TCP; Host IP 127.0.0.1; Host port 2222; Guest Port 22.

**2.** tcp2375; TCP; No Host IP; Host port 2375; Guest Port 2375.

The second adapter is a Host only adapter named vboxnet0, the only setting is deny promiscuous mode.

When I run my docker from inside of the coreOS I usual expose the port 5000 using '-p 5000:5000'.

From the Linux terminal I can ping the CoreOS IP, but I can't ping the Container IP.

Comment: I did it, I have used the same IP as the CoreOS to create the Container '-p <CoreOS IP>::5000', and when starting the cloud9 I used the flag '-l 0.0.0.0 -p 5000', now it is working, Thanks